# how can i open link in href with selenium python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The link inside the href is constantly changing but the xpath of this href is always the same.
How can I click on the [www.confirmationemail.com](http://www.confirmationemail.com) ?

```html
<div dir="ltr">
<p>exampleTEXT.</p>
<p><a href="www.confirmationemail.com" target="_blank">www.confirmationemail.com</a></p>
<p>exampleTEXT.</p>
<p>exampleTEXT,</p>
<p>exampleTEXT</p>
</div>
```

This is the page I'm working on:https://www.minuteinbox.com/

The process is as follows: registering on a site with the e-mail received from here and receiving an e-mail, logging in to the e-mail, but I cannot click on the link in its content.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import config2 as cf
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from asyncio import sleep
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe")


url = "https://www.minuteinbox.com/"
url2 = "EXAMPLE.COM"

driver.get(url)

element =     driver.find_element_by_xpath("XPATH").text
print(element)

time.sleep(4)



driver.execute_script("window.open('');")

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.get(url2)

sec = driver.find_element_by_xpath("XPATH")
sec.click()

devam = driver.find_element_by_xpath("XPATH")
devam.click()

ad = driver.find_element_by_xpath("XPATH")
ad.send_keys("deneme")

soyad = driver.find_element_by_xpath("XPATH")
soyad.send_keys("test")

eMail = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#user_email")
eMail.send_keys(element)

eMail2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#user_email_confirmation")
eMail2.send_keys(element)

sifre = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#user_password")
sifre.send_keys("PASS")

sifre2 =     driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#user_password_confirmation")
sifre2.send_keys("PASS")

buton = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("SELECT")
buton.click()

hesapol = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("SELECT")
hesapol.click()
sleep(2)

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
time.sleep(7)

bas = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#schranka > tr:nth-child(1)")
bas.click()

time.sleep(1)

time.sleep(1)
SD = driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe#iframeMail"))
time.sleep(5)       
SD = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'minuteinbox')]").click

driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

sd = I put this just to be able to write it in the code section

**SOLVED**

*İMPORTS*

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

```
bas = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#schranka > tr:nth-child(1)")
bas.click()
time.sleep(3)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,  "iframe[id='iframeMail']")))
print(driver.page_source)


link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/p[2]/a")
link.click()
```

Comment: _link inside the href is constantly changing but the xpath of this href is always the same_: What do you mean by that?

Comment: When I copy the href xpath it's always the same but every time I open the page it's a different link

Comment: @Prophet  I tried but I get this error:       Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/p[2]/a"}

Comment: 1) possibly you are missing a delay 2) can you share all your code and if possible including the link to the page you are trying to work on?

Comment: Why your code starts from this `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])` ? We don't know what you've written before this.

Comment: It's difficult to understand the code flow by seeing that little code. Update the question so that we can understand what exactly is going on?

Comment: @cruisepandey I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, the XPath of that element is constant.
So you can get that element based the constant XPath locator and click it.
Something like this:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('the_constant_xpath').click()
```

**UPD**
The element you want to be clicked can be located by XPath.
However, it is inside an iframe, so in order to access it you will have to switch to that iframe first.
I have also made your locators better.
So your code could be something like this:

```py
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
time.sleep(5)

bas = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("td.from")
bas.click()

time.sleep(1)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe#iframeMail"))

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'minuteinbox')]").click
```

When you finished working inside the iframe you will have to get out to the default content with

```py
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```